# A model which belongs_to another gets me the no route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, associations

I'm making my first Rails application and mistakes abound. I've searched for "no route matches" questions, but I couldn't find one that fit my problem.

I have a User model. It has_many :tasks and it has_one :pet. Both Task and Pet models belong_to :user. Task and Pet have no pages of their own, they appear on User's page. With Task, this works fine. Here's the show action in users_controller.rb

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @tasks = @user.tasks.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @pet = @user.pet
end
```

I have a feed of @tasks on the @user show.html.erb page, as well as a form for creating tasks. I also have a form for creating a @pet. However, when I click the submit button on the @pet creation form, it goes to an error page.

> Routing Error. No route matches [PATCH] "/pet/1"

Strangely, looking at the routes, I see this:

```
       tasks POST   /tasks(.:format)           tasks#create
        task DELETE /tasks/:id(.:format)       tasks#destroy
   pet_index POST   /pet(.:format)             pet#create
         pet DELETE /pet/:id(.:format)         pet#destroy
        root GET    /                          static_pages#home
```

pet#create has the address pet_index, even though I certainly did not do that on purpose. A user only has one pet, a pet index would make no sense. I created the Pets model in the same way I did the Tasks model, but somewhere, something went wrong. The differences between the two have to do with the fact that there are several @tasks that are created and destroyed, while the pet is just one.

Here is pets_controller.rb

```
class PetsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user


  def create
    @pet = current_user.build_pet(pet_params)
    if @pet.save
      flash[:success] = "Your pet is ready!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private

    def pet_params
      params.require(:pet).permit(:nome)
    end
end
```

I also have a shared/_pet.html.erb partial which contains code that can't access the user.

```
<%= @user.pet.nil? ?  "Pet name" : @user.pet.name %>
```

If I put

```
<%= render 'shared/pet' %>
```

in home.html.erb, it gives me this error:

> NoMethodError in StaticPages#home. undefined method `pet' for
>   nil:NilClass

It's a mess. I appreciate any help.

EDIT: Here's the pet creation form, in shared/pet_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@pet) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :name, placeholder: "Give your pet a name." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Meet pet", class: "btn btn-small btn-default" %>
<% end %>
```

EDIT 2: Here's config/routes.rb

```
Petrefa::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :tasks, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :pet, only: [:create, :destroy]
  root  'static_pages#home'
  match '/register',  to: 'users#new',            via: 'get'
  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help',    via: 'get'
  match '/developers',   to: 'static_pages#about',   via: 'get'
  match '/login',  to: 'sessions#new',         via: 'get'
  match '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy',     via: 'delete'
end
```

EDIT 3: After having changed `form_for(@pet) do` into `form_for(@pet, method: :create, action: '/pet') do` this is the resulting HTML

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/pet/1" class="edit_pet" id="edit_pet_1" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="create"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="fC/PjvsGPG1sKSGvzFSFfzSKAhUZv99w6fkmiRkLRU0="></div>

  <div class="field">
    <textarea id="pet_nome" name="pet[nome]" placeholder="Dê um nome para o seu petRefa.">fulano</textarea>
  </div>
  <input class="btn btn-small btn-default" name="commit" type="submit" value="Conhecer pet">
</form>
```

Comment: Try `form_for(@pet, method: :create) do`

Comment: @vmarquet, that did change No route matches [PATCH] "/pet/1" into No route matches [POST] "/pet/1", but otherwise, the problem remains.

Comment: I read too quickly your routes. `pet_index POST   /pet(.:format)             pet#create` is weird. We should look at the creation of these routes, so can you post your `config/routes.rb`?

Comment: You're POSTing at `/pet/1`, so you should have a route that takes a POST at `/pet/:id(.:format)` (notice the `:id` that is missing in your route).

Comment: @vmarquet but if I do that, won't it create a new page for /pet/1? I don't want the pet to have its own page, I want it to appear on users/show.html.erb just like the tasks do. EDIT: I see that the task does have an id. That was created automatically. How do I put the missing :id on the route? Create the route by hand?

Comment: @vmarquet Should I just manually create the route like this:     `get    'pet/:id' => 'pets#create', :as => 'post' ` ?

Comment: I was mistaken in my (now deleted) previous comment. You CAN'T expect to create a new object in a database by POSTing at `/pet/1`, because the id (here `1`) is only attributed AFTER the creation of the object, not before. So the problem here is that you shouldn't be POSTing at `/pet/1` but only at `/pet`. Still a form problem I think.

Comment: Try `form_for(@pet, method: :create, action: '/pet') do` and don't change the route.

Comment: @vmarquet still the same thing. I'll copy the form HTML by inspecting the page and post it on the question, maybe that'll shed some light.

Comment: My bad. The URL at which you are POSTing is the URL of `@pet` (first argument of your `form_for`. You can't create a new object by POSTing at the adress of an already existing object. Try `form_for("/pet", method: :create) do`

Comment: @vmarquet now I'm getting an error on the actual page where the form is. So I can't even access the form. I don't think that's it, because in the task form and the user form, I had `form_for(@user)` and `form_for(@task)` and it was fine..

Comment: If you want to use `form_for(@pet, method: :create) do`, then `@pet` should be set previously to a new pet object: `@pet = Pet.new` that is NOT already persisted in the database. Before, `form_for(@pet)` was generating the URL `/pet/1` meaning that what you had in your `@pet` was the first pet saved in your database.

Comment: @vmarquet Yes, that was a very stupid mistake, I was trying to test the form while logged as a user who I had created a pet for in the rails console. Now I have logged in as a different user who does not have a pet, and it gives me this error: First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty. I've also tried `form_for(@pet, method: :create)` and `form_for(@pet, method: :create, action: '/pet')`. So I need to set @pet to a new object? In the controller, I thought `@pet = current_user.build_pet(pet_params)` was essentially doing that.

Comment: You're mistaken. `@pet = current_user.build_pet(pet_params)` is the code in the controller which RECIEVES the request (and this code builds the Pet object from the form inputs). The code `@pet = Pet.new` should be in the controller that creates the page where the form is.

Comment: I see. In the Users controller, I have `@pet = @user.pet`, which is the same as with the tasks, `@tasks = @user.tasks.paginate(page: params[:page])` I changed `@pet = @user.pet` into `@pet = Pet.new` and it gave me a new error: undefined method `pets_path' At this point I'm considering getting rid of this model and starting over again with a new one.

Comment: Where does the `pets_path` error comes from? Are you using it directly? This is normal that this method doesn't exist, `pets_path` would be the path of the index page of the pets, but you don't have an index page. It would have been created if you had added `:index` to the `only` array in the line `resources :pet, only: [:create, :destroy]`.

Comment: @vmarquet exactly, it's really weird. I'm not using it directly. pets_path isn't supposed to exist. The mind boggles.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to create a pet, you should use POST and not PATCH request. A POST request will be redirected to the create method, whereas a PATCH request will be redirected to the update method, which doesn't exist and has no route for it in your `PetsController`. You can specify which action (like POST or PATCH) to use in the HTML form.

Secondly, are you sure that you set `@user` in `StaticPages#home`? That could be the reason for the `` undefined method `pet' for nil:NilClass` ``.

Also, I think that to render a partial, you should use `<%= render partial: 'shared/pet' %>`

Comment: I'm using form_for. The weird thing is I also used form_for with the tasks, and it worked fine. I'm not sure how to access the HTML form considering rails does the work of translating the form_for into the real form. I'll edit my original post with the pet creation form.